# grails war build target - how to specify "DO NOT COMPRESS"?

Tags: grails, build

Hi I want to build my wars in grails without compression to optimize rsync transfer.  How can I specify this option?

As shown here, I want compress=false, as in
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html

I specifically want to know how to do it using the grails war task target, i.e., something like

$ grails war -compress=false

Can anyone tell me how to do this??

Thanks!
Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/war.html) for the `war` command there is no such option. The only way you'll be able to achieve this is by writing your [own grails command](http://grails.org/Command+Line+Scripting) (using GAnt) that invokes the underlying Ant task with the `compress=false` option. You should then put this in the `scripts` directoy of your app or a plugin if you want to reuse it across several apps.

Answer (score 3):

Both the jar and war plugins now have an entryCompression property.

Example:

```
war {
     entryCompression = ZipEntryCompression.STORED
}
```

From [Gradle API Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War:entryCompression%22API%20Doc%22)

> The compression level of the entries of the archive. If set to ZipEntryCompression.DEFLATED (the default), each entry is compressed using the DEFLATE algorithm. If set to ZipEntryCompression.STORED the entries of the archive are left uncompressed.